# QGIS "Align Edge" equivalent?

Tags: qgis, features, alignment

I'm trying to move from Arc to QGIS, and spend a lot of time making maps out of polygon features. One tool that I can't find is an equivalent to ArcGIS' topology tool "Align Edge" - is there such a thing or do people have an alternative solution?

Comment: Perhaps the plugin [Generalizer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/generalizer/) or the GRASS tool [v.generalize](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.generalize.html) may be the closest equivalent as these contain simplifying and smoothing algorithms.

Comment: Please explain what "Align edge" does for those of us who know QGIS but don't have access to ArcGIS.

Comment: The Align Edge tool means allows users in Arc Map to edit one polygon feature's geometry and then use this topology tool to match the edges back up again (or fill a hole if an adjoining feature has been removed). This works for gaps or overlaps.

Comment: Unfortunately the generalisation tools wouldn't be able to solve this, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I was able to get this done via using avoid overlapping feature then creating a new polygon and then merging ... it is very fast if you setup keyboard shortkeys
1. Hit Ctrl+. to create new feture

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this done via using avoid overlapping feature then creating a new polygon and then merging, it is very fast if you setup keyboard shortkeys. Almost same time as ArcMap align Edge and I found it better.

1. Hit Ctrl+. to create new feature
2. Draw Polygon (it will align to edges since avoid overlapping polygon is on)
3. Select the two polygons
4. Hit M(setup this keyboard shortkey) to merge two features.